# google script duplicate, rename, copy range only value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using following script to copy, rename and substitute formulas with plain text.. it's working fine but I would like to transform in plain text only a specific range of source sheet ("A1:N11") not the whole new sheet created. The original sheet should still have formulas untouched.

I hope somebody could help me..

thank you!

```
 function copyrenamevalueonly() {
    const sheetName = "VUOTO";
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
    const myValue = sheet.getRange("NUOVO!C9").getDisplayValue();
    const range = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName).copyTo(ss).setName(myValue).showSheet().getDataRange();
    range.copyTo(range, {contentsOnly:true});
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to copy the range of "A1:N11" of the source sheet as the values without formulas.

or

- You want to copy the source sheet and want to convert the range of "A1:N11" as the values without formulas.

In your showing script, all values of the source sheet are copied.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Pattern 1:

In this modification, the range of "A1:N11" of the source sheet is copied as the values without formulas.

```js
function copyrenamevalueonly() {
  const sheetName = "VUOTO";
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const myValue = sheet.getRange("NUOVO!C9").getDisplayValue();
  const dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName).copyTo(ss).setName(myValue);
  dstSheet.getRange(12, 1, dstSheet.getLastRow() - 11, dstSheet.getLastColumn()).clear();
  const range = dstSheet.getDataRange();
  range.copyTo(range, { contentsOnly: true });
}
```

#### Pattern 2:

In this modification, the source sheet is copied and the range of "A1:N11" is converted as the values without formulas.

```js
function copyrenamevalueonly() {
  const sheetName = "VUOTO";
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const myValue = sheet.getRange("NUOVO!C9").getDisplayValue();
  const dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName).copyTo(ss).setName(myValue);
  const range = dstSheet.getRange("A1:N11");
  range.copyTo(range, { contentsOnly: true });
}
```

#### Note:

- From `it's working fine` in your question, I guessed that you might want to also copy the formats. So, I modified it like the above.

Comment: the second one is perfect!  I only have to had  '.showSheet().' because my source sheet is not visible but new one has to become visible to be modified..

Comment: please explain how to accept your reply..